# Prove that the principal logarithm ($Log$) is a bijection between $\mathbb{C}-[0,\infty)$ and $\Omega=\{z \in \mathbb{C} | -\pi < Im(z) <\pi\}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm doing this exercise:

> Prove that the principal logarithm ($Log$) is a bijection between $\mathbb{C}-[0,\infty)$ and $\Omega=\{z\in\mathbb{C}|-\pi<Im(z)<\pi\}$

First of all, I understand that  $\mathbb{C}-[0,\infty)$ is referring to the set of all complex numbers minus the positive real axis, right? Is it the notation we have to use?

When we have this solved, I have to see that $Log$ is injective ($Log(a)=Log(b) \iff a=b$) and that is exhaustive. Then, we're done, right?

I'd like some hints because I'm confused by this problem's notation.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yes, that is the intent of the slightly ambiguous notation. The notation $[a,b]$ usually refers to the segment joining $a,b$, but $\infty$ is a bit ambiguous in $\mathbb{C}$. However, it is a common notation.

Comment: I presume it is $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$? The value $1$ is certainly in the domain of the principal branch of $\log$.

Comment: @copper.hat I copied it exactly as it's on my notes, maybe it's a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: use polar coordinates. With *some* caveats
$$\log(r e^{i\theta}) = \log r + i\theta.$$

Comment: But the goal is to see that $Log(re^{i\theta})=Log(se^{i\alpha}) \iff re^{i\theta}=se^{i\alpha}$, and that every element on $\Omega$ is on $\mathbb{C}-[0,\infty)$ right?

Comment: @Relure, $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty,0]$.

Comment: So it's definitely a book typo right?

Comment: @Relure, is a typo with the *usual* definition of main branch of $\log$.